# unable to set db using string while coding in python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I would like to know if there is a way to set db using a variable

For example: I am coding in Python, and I connect  using `client = MongoClient(uri)`. All goes fine.

There are 4 dbs: test1,test2,test3,test4.
I am able to list them all.

```
dblist = client.list_database_names()
print(dblist)
```

All goes fine.

Now,  Instead of connecting/ using

`db = client.test1`

Is there a way to use a string rather than actual name of the db?

`such as str = 'test1', and then db=client.str.`

(this doesn't work)

In my program , I display the list of dbs first and then I am taking user input on the db , and proceed with further flow, but unable to do so.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add string as an name when it comes to that. However there is another function that takes string of the name of certain database and gets the database.

```
db=client.get_database('test')
```

Here is the documentation: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html

Comment: thank you so much :) . this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Hiii...@fullstackwebdev Just one follow up question, if that's ok. I tried both ways below, and both work, but just curious, if there is any difference at all between the two: 
db = client.get_database(sample_str) and 
db = client[sample_str]......................in both cases the sample_str is a string variable containing the actual name of the db

Comment: Not really, the only difference is when you get an database troughout get_database function you can assign some attributes to it (on example read_preference,write_concern, those are the attributes that come with the function), while when you are using just regular client[sample_str] you can just assign name as the string of the given database. You have everything of this more detailed in their documentation above.

Comment: ok, I understand now. thank you once again and I will read the documentation in detail...:)